# What does "south and to the west of market square" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

[image]

Does this mean that the Meat Hall was south west of market Square?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes directions are rendered this way to put more emphasis on the first direction noted, and less emphasis on the second, but I don't see evidence of that weighting difference in this particular quote.

Comment: @DanBron It does give the impression that one heads south before going west to get there.  If it meant south by south west (more south than west) it could have been qualified such as "south and a little to the west".

Comment: This kind of direction-giving is typical in cities whose streets were laid out on a grid pattern. https://www.google.com/search?q=philadelphia+street+map&num=20&newwindow=1&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=Pewz8NJLOmjnPM%253A%253BfdDGslg5RkakHM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.aaccessmaps.com%25252Fshow%25252Fmap%25252Fus%25252Fpa%25252Fphiladelphia_overall&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Pewz8NJLOmjnPM%253A%252CfdDGslg5RkakHM%252C_&biw=1107&bih=984&usg=__O2QHHHWwmVIWVYYohzBby_sHeXM%3D&ved=0CEUQyjdqFQoTCI-XnZKKq8cCFcQVHgodP30KUQ&ei=OC_PVY-bHMSreL_6qYgF#imgrc=Pewz8NJLOmjnPM%3A&usg=__O2QHHHWwmVIWVYYohzBby_sHeXM%3D

Comment: The wording would imply that the location is, very roughly, "south-southwest".  Or that the appropriate route from Market Square is to go south first, then west, since the placement of roads somehow limits your options.  (Or the guy could simply be attempting to be "poetic".)

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the Meat Hall was south west of market Square?

Yes, but to get there walk south and then west. It is normal for location information to describe how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the Meat Hall was south west of market Square?

Yes!

Any way of getting there would work, including a diagonal street.